# Moving a toilet

Tags: joists, remodeling

How difficult/expensive would it be to move a toilet across joists?

My bathroom is over a garage so I can get to it from below.
[image]

Comment: Cost questions are off-topic here, and the matter of difficulty is completely subjective. Please revise to add detail and ask something more specific. In particular, show us your plumbing and framing.

Comment: I recently moved a toilet. Called the plumber, they gave me a quote. When I had the money I called them in. Moving a toilet yourself might be illegal in your area.

Answer (score 4):

Moving the toilet is trivial. Moving the pipe is not, unless you can run the pipe below the joists, so you don't have to cut through any. Cutting through joists to provide space to run a soil pipe ranges from difficult to impossible, depending on specifics of joist size and where the plumbing needs to go.

Or perhaps I should clarify that as "difficult to impossible if you don't want the floor and/or building to fall down" since you might be of the "but I can cut holes, no problem" persuasion.